# How can I access the values of text view in the view holder and convert it to string and use it in if else statement for comparison

Tags: string, android-recyclerview, textview, android-viewholder

How can I access the values of text view in the view holder and convert it to string and use it in if else statement for comparison.

Here is the view holder. I want to use the value of the text view in the same activity . But not in the view holder.

```
public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;


        public FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

> ```
> findFriendViewHolder.userName.setText("Random value");
> ```